# Symfony email-verification - expired link

Tags: symfony, security, email-verification

I made the security process in my symfony app.

That allready works, but if the email-verify link is expired, how to make a new link "request a new link." ? Like is asked on this picture :
[The link to verify your email has expired](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W8UEE.png)

I made the security of symfony, everything works, but, I don't know where I can find how to make the "request a new link" when the link is expired.

Here is the security YAML

```
    security:
        # https://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html#registering-the-user-hashing-passwords
        password_hashers:
            Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\PasswordAuthenticatedUserInterface: 'auto'
        # https://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html#loading-the-user-the-user-provider
        providers:
            # used to reload user from session & other features (e.g. switch_user)
            app_user_provider:
                entity:
                    class: App\Entity\User
                    property: email
        firewalls:
            dev:
                pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
                security: false
            main:
                lazy: true
                provider: app_user_provider
                login_throttling:
                    max_attempts: 3
                logout:
                    path: app_logout
                form_login:
                    login_path: app_login
                    check_path: app_login
                    default_target_path: app_member
                remember_me:
                    secret:   '%kernel.secret%' # required
                    lifetime: 604800 # 1 week in seconds

        access_control:
            # - { path: ^/admin, roles: ROLE_ADMIN }
            - { path: ^/member, roles: ROLE_USER }
```

Here is the RegistrationController
<?php

```
    namespace App\Controller;

    use App\Entity\User;
    use App\Form\RegistrationFormType;
    use App\Repository\UserRepository;
    use App\Security\EmailVerifier;
    use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManagerInterface;
    use Symfony\Bridge\Twig\Mime\TemplatedEmail;
    use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\AbstractController;
    use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
    use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
    use Symfony\Component\Mime\Address;
    use Symfony\Component\PasswordHasher\Hasher\UserPasswordHasherInterface;
    use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route;
    use Symfony\Contracts\Translation\TranslatorInterface;
    use SymfonyCasts\Bundle\VerifyEmail\Exception\VerifyEmailExceptionInterface;

    class RegistrationController extends AbstractController
    {
        private EmailVerifier $emailVerifier;

        public function __construct(EmailVerifier $emailVerifier)
        {
            $this->emailVerifier = $emailVerifier;
        }

        #[Route('/register', name: 'app_register')]
        public function register(Request $request, UserPasswordHasherInterface $userPasswordHasher, EntityManagerInterface $entityManager): Response
        {
            $user = new User();
            $form = $this->createForm(RegistrationFormType::class, $user);
            $form->handleRequest($request);

            if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
                // encode the plain password
                $user->setPassword(
                    $userPasswordHasher->hashPassword(
                        $user,
                        $form->get('plainPassword')->getData()
                    )
                );

                $entityManager->persist($user);
                $entityManager->flush();

                // generate a signed url and email it to the user
                $this->emailVerifier->sendEmailConfirmation('app_verify_email', $user,
                    (new TemplatedEmail())
                        ->from(new Address('info@anteriority.ch', 'Account Confirmation'))
                        ->to($user->getEmail())
                        ->subject('Please Confirm your Email')
                        ->htmlTemplate('registration/confirmation_email.html.twig')
                );
                // do anything else you need here, like send an email

                return $this->redirectToRoute('app_login');
            }

            return $this->render('registration/register.html.twig', [
                'registrationForm' => $form->createView(),
            ]);
        }

        #[Route('/verify/email', name: 'app_verify_email')]
        public function verifyUserEmail(Request $request, TranslatorInterface $translator, UserRepository $userRepository): Response
        {
            $id = $request->query->get('id');

            if (null === $id) {
                return $this->redirectToRoute('app_register');
            }

            $user = $userRepository->find($id);

            if (null === $user) {
                return $this->redirectToRoute('app_register');
            }

            // validate email confirmation link, sets User::isVerified=true and persists
            try {
                $this->emailVerifier->handleEmailConfirmation($request, $user);
            } catch (VerifyEmailExceptionInterface $exception) {
                $this->addFlash('verify_email_error', $translator->trans($exception->getReason(), [], 'VerifyEmailBundle'));

                return $this->redirectToRoute('app_register');
            }

            // @TODO Change the redirect on success and handle or remove the flash message in your templates
            $this->addFlash('success', 'Your email address has been verified.');

            return $this->redirectToRoute('app_register');
        }
    }
```

Here is the EmailVerifier

```
    <?php

    namespace App\Security;

    use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManagerInterface;
    use Symfony\Bridge\Twig\Mime\TemplatedEmail;
    use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
    use Symfony\Component\Mailer\MailerInterface;
    use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserInterface;
    use SymfonyCasts\Bundle\VerifyEmail\Exception\VerifyEmailExceptionInterface;
    use SymfonyCasts\Bundle\VerifyEmail\VerifyEmailHelperInterface;

    class EmailVerifier
    {
        public function __construct(
            private VerifyEmailHelperInterface $verifyEmailHelper,
            private MailerInterface $mailer,
            private EntityManagerInterface $entityManager
        ) {
        }

        public function sendEmailConfirmation(string $verifyEmailRouteName, UserInterface $user, TemplatedEmail $email): void
        {
            $signatureComponents = $this->verifyEmailHelper->generateSignature(
                $verifyEmailRouteName,
                $user->getId(),
                $user->getEmail(),
                ['id' => $user->getId()]
            );

            $context = $email->getContext();
            $context['signedUrl'] = $signatureComponents->getSignedUrl();
            $context['expiresAtMessageKey'] = $signatureComponents->getExpirationMessageKey();
            $context['expiresAtMessageData'] = $signatureComponents->getExpirationMessageData();

            $email->context($context);

            $this->mailer->send($email);
        }

        /**
         * @throws VerifyEmailExceptionInterface
         */
        public function handleEmailConfirmation(Request $request, UserInterface $user): void
        {
            $this->verifyEmailHelper->validateEmailConfirmation($request->getUri(), $user->getId(), $user->getEmail());

            $roles = [];
            $roles[] = "ROLE_MEMBER";
            $user->setRoles($roles);
            $user->setIsVerified(true);

            $this->entityManager->persist($user);
            $this->entityManager->flush();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Create a new action which will:
a) Check if user is still not verified
b) Regenerate signed email and send it once again

Something like this in the **RegistrationController**:

```
    #[Route('/verify/request', name: 'app_request_verification_email')]
    public function requestVerificationEmail(Request $request, TranslatorInterface $translator, UserRepository $userRepository): Response
    {
        $id = $request->query->get('id');

        if (null === $id) {
            return $this->redirectToRoute('app_register');
        }

        $user = $userRepository->find($id);

        if (null === $user) {
            return $this->redirectToRoute('app_register');
        }

        if ($user->isVerified() && $user->hasRole("ROLE_MEMBER")) {
            $this->addFlash('already_verified', $translator->trans($exception->getReason(), [], 'VerifyEmailBundle'));

            return $this->redirectToRoute('app_register');
        }

        $this->emailVerifier->sendEmailConfirmation('app_verify_email', $user,
            (new TemplatedEmail())
                ->from(new Address('info@anteriority.ch', 'Account Confirmation'))
                ->to($user->getEmail())
                ->subject('Please Confirm your Email')
                ->htmlTemplate('registration/confirmation_email.html.twig')
            );

        $this->addFlash('success', 'New verification link has been sent');

        return $this->redirectToRoute('app_register');
    }
```